# Identify uniques on combination of 2 columns in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am working with somewhat weird data. I want to identify unique records with columns having many to many relationship like in example below. Column B can be null, column A is non-null:

[image: Data]

Output should be 2 unique values. The combinations of A and B (1,A), (1,B), (1,null), (2,B) are all only a single unique entity and rest are the second unique entity.

EDIT: 
My requirement is not just finding distinct values. Imagine it's like user sessions - user A can have multiple sessions, but they can log in with different log ins ( such as B) and have same session id (1) and vice versa. I want to identify unique users based on session and log in where sessions and log ins can be n:n

Comment: Do you want to write query for fetching unique records?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using SQLITE3:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ColumnA || Column B)
FROM Table;
```

For MYSQL I think it is:

```
SELECT CONCAT(ColumnA, ColumnB)
FROM Table;
```

I'm not sure how you want to output null values. You have 2 options:

1. If A has Null value and B has a value, output B
2. If A has null value and B has a value, output nullB

For Option 1 use the code above. For Option 2, you'll have to update the columnA database to replace all null values with the text 'null'.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select distinct a, b
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and
                        t2.b not in ('A', 'B')
                 );
```

This select `id`s that have only `'A'`, `'B'`, or `NULL` values in the second column.

Comment: Edited the questions. I am looking to identify unique records based on combination of 2 columns - user sessions and log in ids where both can be n:n and I want to identify unique persons